# What is an alternative definition of local homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

The definition I was given is for local homeomorphism:

> " Let $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\tau_1)$ be topological spaces. A map $f:X \to Y$ is said to be a local homeomorphism if each point $x \in X$ has an open neighbourhood $U$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $U$ maps $U$ homeomorphically onto an open subspace $V$ of $(Y,\tau_1)$; that is, if the topology induced on $U$ by $\tau$ is $\tau_2$ and the topology induced on $V=f(U)$ by $\tau_1$ is $\tau_3$, then $f$ is a homeomorphism of $ (U,\tau_2)$ onto $(V,\tau_3)$. The topological space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be locally homeomorphic to $(Y,\tau_1)$ if there exists a local homeomorphism of $(X,\tau)$ into $(Y,\tau_1)$."

Are there any alternative definitions that are better or gives more insight into what exactly local homeomorphisms are? Or are there better definitions out there that makes it easier when doing proofs.

Comment: Personally, I'd say the first one is fine. There is an imprecision in the part after "that is," because the definition given is equivalent to that condition plus $f$ being globally open (or plus $f(U)$ being open for all $U$ as mentioned).

Comment: Learn MathJax please.

Comment: There is basic MathJax tutorial and reference guide [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

The following rephrasing may be easier to think about at first, although ultimately you should be comfortable with the given one:

> A map $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is a local homeomorphism iff there is some open cover $\mathcal{C}$ of $X$ such that for each $U\in \mathcal{C}$, $f[U]$ is open as a subset of $Y$ and $f\upharpoonright U$ is a homeomorphism between the subspaces $U$ of $X$ and $f[U]$ of $Y$.

(It's a good exercise to prove that this is in fact equivalent to the definition given by the text.)

This rephrasing captures the idea that $f$ is a local homeomorphism iff we can "break $X$ into pieces" such that $f$ looks like a homeomorphism from the perspective of each piece. We have to be careful, though: "break into pieces" suggests *disjoint* pieces, and that's definitely not wanted here. Hence the more technical language of open covers: $\mathcal{C}$ is just supposed to be some collection of open sets which together account for all the points in $X$, they don't have to be disjoint.

For what it's worth, I'd say that when starting out the original definition is meaningfully easier to use in proofs, while the rephrasing above is slightly easier to grasp conceptually. But that's just my own experience with a small number of students.

Answer (score 1):

This definition is fine of doing proofs. You could (should?) check that a circle in the plane is locally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ and the $\{x \in \Bbb R^3\mid \|x\|=1\}$, a sphere surface, is locally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$. The notion mostly comes up when studying manifolds. It's not an important notion outside of that area, really.